# ISO and aperture not syncing with flash over wireless triggers

Tags: nikon, flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, nikon-d3200

I’m using Nikon d3200 and Neewer VK750II Flash, off camera, with neewer fc16 trigger and receiver.
In TTL mode, the flash fires correctly with the shutter speed but it doesn’t sync ISO or angle (aperture) with the camera. 
The flash works correctly if mounted directly on the hot shoe.

Is this normal? Should I use other triggers? 
Also, how can I add a second external falsh, with the same setup.

Answer (score 1):

The FC16 is not TTL capable, it is only a manual trigger/receiver and it doesn't transmit any data other than the firing signal.
If you want automatic power adjustments based on ISO/Ap then you need TTL capable trigger/receiver. And it you want to add another flash you need a second receiver for it.

Answer (score 1):

While the D3200 and your Neewer-branded* Voking VK750 II can both communicate iTTL signals, the Neewer-branded Godox FC16 Rx/Tx triggers cannot.

If you look at the pin on the foot of the transmitter, and the hotshoe on top of the receiver, you'll notice there's only a single pin/contact. This is the way the sync (fire) signal is communicated.  All the other information for power adjustment via TTL, high-speed sync, camera menu communication, non-TTL Auto communication, etc. happens on the other three pins of the Nikon hotshoe/flash foot.

So there's no way for the flash to know what ISO/aperture is set on your camera. For that, you'd required iTTL-compatible triggers, with full hotshoe communication.

> Is this normal?

Yes. This is what is meant by "manual only" triggers (or flashes). Nothing else is communicated other than the sync signal. You can, of course, use the speedlight in M mode, and adjust the power on the flash itself, if you want to use these triggers.

> Should I use other triggers?

Personally, I'd recommend a Godox TT685-N speedlight (with built-in radio transceiver) and Flashpoint R2 Pro II-N transmitter as a better (but more expensive) starting point. But what you're possibly looking for would be Yongnuo YN-622N transceivers or Godox X2T-N transmitter and X1R-N receiver.

> Also, how can I add a second external [flash], with the same setup.

You'd have to purchase additional radio triggers to act as receivers for each new flash you add.  Or, if you go with the Godox combo, purchase only the Godox speedlights [in their 2.4 GHz system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/) with built-in radio triggers.

---

- Neewer doesn't actually manufacture anything; they just rebrand gear from a lot of other companies, such as Yongnuo, Godox, Voking, Meike, and Triopo. So just because you have two pieces of gear that are branded as Neewer doesn't mean they were made by the same company, and compatibility can be an issue. That isn't the case here, though.